Issue with state in Redux state always one step behind
I've written the logic for login functionality using Redux-Toolkit (RTK) and these are the components. In the login component, while calling on handle submit, I always get error to be empty the first time and then the second time it gets called, I get the actual state.
I do know that this is about Javascript closures and I should be handling the console.log using a useEffect but what if I need to call multiple asynchronous actions based on the outcome of login action. How would I write code for this?
For example, something like this:
function handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  dispatch(login(email, password));
  if (loginError) return;
  dispatch(fetchCustomerProfile(id))
  if(fetchError) return;
  dispatch(hideModal("login")
}

This is how my code looks right now:
const Login = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const error = useSelector(getError);

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(login(email, password));
    if (error) console.log("Const");
  }

  return (
    <form
      className="mt-4 flex flex-col m-[44px]"
      onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}
    >
      <FormInput
        label="Email ID"
        name="emailID"
        type="text"
        value={email}
        setValue={setEmail}
      />
      <FormInput
        label="Password"
        name="password"
        type="password"
        value={password}
        setValue={setPassword}
        className="mt-3"
      />
      {error && <h3>Error Occuerd</h3>}
      <Button
        className="mt-6 ml-auto w-full bg-yellow-500 text-black"
        name={"Login"}
      />
    </form>
  );
};

authSlice.js
const initialState = {
  user: {},
  error: "",
  status: {},
};

const login = createAsyncThunk("auth/login", async ({ email, password }) => {
  try {
    const { payload: user } = await authAPI.login(email, password);
    return user;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error.message);
  }
});

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState,
  extraReducers: (builder) =>
    builder
      .addCase(login.pending, (state) => {
        state.status = "pending";
        state.error = "";
      })
      .addCase(login.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
        state.status = "fullfilled";
        state.error = "";
        state.user = payload;
      })
      .addCase(login.rejected, (state, { error }) => {
        state.status = "rejected";
        state.error = error.message;
        console.log(state.error);
      }),
});

export default authSlice.reducer;

export const getError = (state) => state.auth.error;

export { login };


This is a stale closure issue, in that that selected loginError and fetchError values from the render cycle that handleSubmit is called are closed over in the callback scope and will never be a different value.
A somewhat trivial solution would be to await the actions to settle and access the store instance and get the current state value on-demand. See useStore.
Example:
import { useDispatch, useSelector, useStore } from 'react-redux';

...

const store = useStore();
const loginError = useSelector(selectLoginError);
const fetchError = useSelector(selectFetchError);

async function handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  await dispatch(login({ email, password }));
  if (selectLoginError(store.getState())) return;
  await dispatch(fetchCustomerProfile(selectUser(store.getState()).id));
  if (selectFetchError(store.getState())) return;
  dispatch(hideModal("login");
}

This is not the recommended way to use the store though. It appears that both login and fetchCustomerProfile are asynchronous actions, so you can await them to resolve and unwrap the results. If there was an error in the asynchronous action a Promise rejection is returned and the handler can catch and handle it. See Handling Thunk Results for details.
Example:
async function handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  try {
    // log in with user credentials
    const user = await dispatch(login({ email, password })).unwrap();

    // login success, fetch customer profile
    await dispatch(fetchCustomerProfile(user.id)).unwrap();

    // fetch success, hide modal
    dispatch(hideModal("login");
  } catch(error) {
    // handle/ignore any rejected Promises or thrown errors
  } finally {
    // any final logic you want to run regardless of success/failure
  }
}

